# Non-django analogue to manage.py

Tags: python, command

I'm looking for some python package providing basic functionality for writing and executing project-specific commands using some common interface. There is no problem to write it myself, but I already saw a project like this somewhere, so would you help me to remember it?

Comment: The manage.py commands are django-specific so I'm not sure what you expect this package to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't need manage.py commands, I want cli tool acting as facade to my own commands and ability to write this commands

Answer (score 0):

[fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html) can do this but it's more geared towards deployment and other such tasks. [Scons](http://www.scons.org/) is a build tool similar to make which can have custom commands. [Paver](http://paver.github.com/paver/) is also like make/rake for doing things like this. You can also [add custom commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446682/how-to-make-easy-install-execute-custom-commands-in-setup-py) to the distutils `setup.py` script. The standard libary [cmd module](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) is a lighter version.

Comment: No, sorry, nothing appropriate

Comment: Well then I think you need to rephrase your question. What exactly are you looking for? Setup.py lets you write to custom commands exactly the way that you do for manage.py.

Comment: @dir01 - You know, this answer is probably as close as you are going to get without more information. You asking for everyone to help you remember some existing package yet nothing anyone suggests meets your hidden agenda. I would say this question is close to being voted down unless you give everyone some more direction. Are you trying to create build options? What? If all you want is arbitrary commands, then just create a dictionary that maps words to functions and pass along the rest of the args. A simple google search for `python optparse subcommands` returns this: http://goo.gl/ybqu5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are thinking of [paster](http://pythonpaste.org/paster/)?

Comment: AFAIK, paster is for web only. My app is not a WSGI app at all

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new argparse package which is a standard Python package to parse command line options http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse
Django's manage.py probably uses that as well but I have not looked at the code so I can't confirm.