# calling external script during python package install

Tags: python, setup.py

I am interested in building a Windows distribution for my application.

The application requires that a number of environmental variables and/or registry entries be set for the software to function properly. Supposing I write a script 'set_vars.py' to create and set these entries, is there a way to call this script when the application is installed via

```
python setup.py install
```

From the documentation detailing 'setup.py', I did not see an obvious way to call pre-install or post-install scripts.

I would rather not have set_vars.py called from an **init**.py in the distribution because the variables only really need to be set up once at install time.

Comment: This doesn't make your prospects sound good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1621540/63225

Comment: Does the accepted answer to [How can I add post-install scripts to easy_install / setuptools / distutils?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/253103/355230) help?

Comment: Despite searching for some time, I completely missed those two previous questions/answers. The comment "You can add your subcommand to install.sub_commands, and pass the command into setup()." from the latter question may do the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the needed action scripted, you could just `--install-script=set_vars.py` to your call to `setup.py`, or, even better (for convenience), add the option to your `setup.cfg` file.